# How can I send data between two pages in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The specific case is that I use one page `filter.jsx` to get the request from the user like the subject, the grade of student, the difficulty level, ... Then I process them via an API `filter/route.js` to filter the question database and send the filtered data back to the page `filter.jsx`.

How can I create a button in `filter.jsx` that when clicked will move to other page `test.jsx` and use the filtered data in this `test.jsx` page?

I used Link and router.push but they dont work. Maybe I was using it the wrong way.

Comment: Next 13 or Next 14?

Comment: Nextjs 14. But I can use both the syntax for nextjs13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.  One would be to use URL parameters in the `<Link>` from the `filter.jsx` page to `test.jsx`, like

```
const filterValue = "some-value";
...
href={`/whatever/url/test-is-at?filter=${filterValue}`}
...
```

Then you can get this in the `test.jsx` page via

Next 14:

```
export default function Page() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const filterValue = searchParams.filter;  // some-value
...
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

Next 13:

```
export default function Page({searchParams}) {
    const filterValue = searchParams.filter;  // some-value
...
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional

Probably your filter value is in state so that when your API call resolves, you set the state and it updates the href in your `Link`, but you probably knew that already :)

Answer (score 1):

You can acheave this using two methods:

1. URL Parameters or Query Strings.
2. Next.js API Routes for Server-Side Data Fetching.

---

**1. URL Parameters or Query Strings.**

In Filter.jsx:

```
const router = useRouter();

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const filteredData = await fetchFilteredData();
  router.push({
    pathname: '/test',
    query: { subject: filteredData.subject, grade: filteredData.grade }, // Example query parameters
  });
};
```

Test.jsx:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Test = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { subject, grade } = router.query;

  // Use subject and grade as needed
};
```

**2. Next.js API Routes for Server-Side Data Fetching.**

In filter.jsx:

```
const handleNavigate = () => {
  router.push(`/test?id=${filteredDataId}`);
};
```

Test.jsx:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { id } = context.query;
  const data = await fetchFilteredDataById(id);
  return { props: { data } };
}
```